# How to read multiple test data files in same script?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I'm trying to use data in multiple test data files in the same script here. Suppose there are 2 data files with login credentials (`Login1.csv` and `Login2.csv`).
I need to use credentials in `Login1.csv` in one environment (on-premise) and credentials in `Login2.csv` in another environment (cloud) and need to use data in both files in the same script. I have created 2 test cases there (test1 and test2) but I have about 50 test cases in the real project.

The script below is working fine for the first csv file (`Login1.csv`) but I'm not sure if it's possible to use credentials in `Login2.csv` in same script (in test1 and test2).

```
public class Test_Login2 {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void test1(HashMap<String, String> b) {
        System.out.println(b.get("Username"));
        System.out.println(b.get("Password"));
        System.out.println("*************************");
        // -------------other scripts----------------
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void test2(HashMap<String, String> b) {
        System.out.println(b.get("Username"));
        System.out.println(b.get("Password"));
        System.out.println("*************************");
        // -------------other scripts----------------
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] dpmethod() throws Exception {

        // test data file for one environment (on-premise)
        String csvfile = "C:\\Users\\.....\\Login1.csv";
        CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        //----------script for reading data in login1 file

        // test data file for another environment (cloud)    
        String csvfile = "C:\\Users\\.....\\Login2.csv";
        CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        //----------script for reading data in login2 file
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the problem? If you are seeing any issues, could you please share it here?

Comment: How to use data in Login2.csv file in Test1 and Test2 testcases ?

Comment: create a separate class that calls the methods of `Test_Login2` and pass `data` as required to that methods from the new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the environment through command line using the `-DEnv="cloud"` option and read it in your code.
Based on the environment, you can use a particular filepath to generate the dataprovider and pass it to your test cases.

```
@DataProvider(name="dp")
public Object[][] dpmethod()throws Exception{
   // Reading the environment variable here.
   String env = System.getProperty("Env");
   String csvFile = null;
   if(env.equals("on-premise")){
      // test data file for one environment (on-premise)
      csvFile = "C:\\Users\\.....\\Login1.csv";
   }else if(env.equals("cloud")){
      //test data file for another environment (cloud)
      csvfile = "C:\\Users\\.....\\Login2.csv";
   }else{
      System.out.println("Unsupported environment.");
      System.exit(0);
   }
   CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
   // code for reading data 
   // from one of the files 
   // and create the data object

   // return the data object created above.
}
```